# python imported matplotlib module shared between different instances?

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib

(I am sort new to python so the class hierarchy of python still isn't quite clear for me)

So I have `ulti.py` which helps me to plot things.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Util:    
    def plot(self, i, data):            
        plt.plot(data[0],data[1])
        plt.title("test" + str(i))
        plt.show()
        plt.savefig("test" + str(i) + '.png')
```

And then when i do

```
from util import Util

uti1 = Util()
uti2 = Util()
print (uti1.plot(1,[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]))
print (uti2.plot(2,[[0,1,2],[2,1,0]]))
```

from another file, to my surprise that the plot from `uti2` instance also have the plot from `uti1` instance overlapped together!

So my question is that is this the same for importing every module in python? I later find out i can add `plt.figure(i)` to evade this problem. But how can I avoid it from a good design of the classes? Or is it python just designed this way.

Comment: Here's a relevant discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993206/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-pyplot-windows-or-am-i-limited-to-subplots (note a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397791/how-can-i-show-figures-separately-in-matplotlib/2399978#2399978!)

Comment: This is where the matplotlib object-oriented approach helps a lot (i.e. use `ax.plot`, `ax.set_title`, etc., instead of `plt.plot`, `plt.title`). See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles