# Plot in function called iteratively results get overwritten

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, subplot

The following function plots stock price and volume when called. However, when it is called to create multiple plots iteratively only the last plot was shown up in output. How to flush the plot outputs to get the multiple plots. Trying the sleep function but it does not work.

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def skplot(ticker,dt1,dt2):
    tck = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    print(ticker+"\n"+"Market      Cap:"+'${:,.0f}'.format(tck.info["marketCap"]))
    df = yf.download(ticker, start=dt1, end=dt2)

    top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
    top.plot(df.index, df["Close"])
    plt.title(ticker)

    bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    bottom.bar(df.index, df['Volume'])

    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,8)

    time.sleep(1)

#this one works
skplot("HLIT","2018-01-01","2019-07-11")

#called in a loop produce only the last chart


def stocklist():
    '''Returns a list of stocks that met the criteria for rsi_plot'''
    l=[   
"HLIT"  ,
"OHRP"  ,
"HELE"  ,
"CY"           ]
    for i in l:
#        print(i)
        skplot(i,"2018-01-01","2019-07-11")
    return

stocklist()
```

Comment: This seems like normal behavior. What are you trying to do with the plots?

Comment: Do you want one figure with multiple *sub*plots or multiple figures?

Comment: I am expecting the following result:  price chart of stock1  and vol ; price chart of stock2 and vol2; price chart of stock3 and vol; etc. Currently the output of Spyder shows only the last price chart and vol . That is stock price of "CY" and vol. If this explains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple PyPlot windows? Or am I limited to subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993206/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-pyplot-windows-or-am-i-limited-to-subplots)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `plt.figure()` right above `top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)`.
If you don't do that, then you will be continuously plotting in the same figure and overwriting it, or so I assume. Can't really test it since my own matplotlib is glitching out rn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single figure that contains all the plots, you need to change the location(row,col) for each plot and remove the `rowspan` and `colspan` arguments:

```
def f(i):
    r,c = divmod(i, 4)
    top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (r, c))
    top.plot(range(10*i), range(10*i))

for i,thing in enumerate(range(16)):
    f(i)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

---

Unless you want your plots to be positioned on something other than a *regular* grid, similar to [these examples](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-subplot2grid), you can just use `plt.subplot`.

```
def g(i):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i)
    plt.plot(range(10*i), range(10*i))

for i,thing in enumerate(range(16),1):
    g(i)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```