# Update of matplotlib graph data series in interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, qtconsole

IPython, QtConsole, `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`, `qt` backend. I need to redraw the plot after updating data series (DataFrame instance) itself.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130341/exact-semantics-of-matplotlibs-interactive-mode-ion-ioff) does not quite does it, since it relates to graph elements themselves being updated, while I want to get them updated on DataFrame modification.

I'm using this function for plotting:

```
def ulegend(df, *columns, **kwargs):
    pyplot.close()
    columns = list(columns)
    col_regex = kwargs.get('col_regex')
    if col_regex:
        colnames = list(df.columns)
        colnames = filter(bool, map(lambda x: re.search(col_regex, x) and x, colnames))
        columns.extend(colnames)
    lines = plot(df[list(columns)])
    pyplot.legend(lines, columns)
    return lines
```

Basic but does the job. `pyplot` returns a list of `Line2D` instances and I have no idea how to change the same line instance as to get it updated with changed df `Series` (is this, i.e. `DataFrame`'s `Series` object that `pyplot` uses for plotting?). This is what I'm after.