# Pylab documentation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I visited the [scipy site for PyLab.](http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab) I could not find its documentation there. The [matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.org/) also does not provide any information on it.

Where can I find a tutorial/documentation on PyLab?

Answer (score 6):

Pylab is basically just Numpy and Matplotlib under a unified namespace. Learn about either of those and you will understand Pylab.

If you want to plot things in scripts it is generally preferred that you use `import matplotlib.pyplot` instead of `import pylab`, but really the choice is up to you.

If you want to have interactive plotting (for instance, by calling `ipython --pylab`) then pylab is the way to go. However `pyplot` can also be put in an interactive mode using `pyplot.ion()`.

Some more information can be found here:

[What is the difference between pylab and pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot)

[Exact semantics of Matplotlib's "interactive mode" (ion(), ioff())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130341/exact-semantics-of-matplotlibs-interactive-mode-ion-ioff)

Comment: I have tried pyplot. I want to update my graph and a question here on SO says for interactive graphs/plots I have to look at pylab, thus I wanted more information about it.

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer. If you can already use `matplotlib`, there is nothing particularly new for you to learn to use `pylab`. The vast majority of the commands are the same.