# return a numpy array from a matplotlib plot is too slow, how can i speed it up?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I speed up the conversion between matplotlib plots to a numpy arrays? 
My program creates millions of plots, and for each plot I want to return its numpy array (I do not care about viewing nor saving the plots! I only care about the conversion to numpy arrrays).

I managed to make the conversion with the following code:

```
data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')

data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
```

Unfortunately, since I use: `fig = plt.figure(num=1)` at the beginning, and `plt.clf()` at the end, the program shows the images one by one on the figure, which slows everything down (about 1 to 2 frames per second).

I'm searching for a faster solution for the conversion from matplotlib plots to numpy arrays.

---

**Update**

I made the aggbackend change, but no improvement, where am I wrong?
I'm attaching my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import imageio
from Game import Init, Draw, Game_step

images = []
Init()
fig = plt.figure(num=1)
Draw()
fig.canvas.draw()

for stp in range(100):
    action_button = np.random.randint(4)
    observation = Game_step(action_button)
    Draw()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
    data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
images.append(data)
imageio.mimsave("game.gif", images, duration=1 / 35)
```

when Init: initialize the game, Draw: plot the current game screenshot in matplotlib, Game_step: taking one action in the game environment
The goal is to get the np array of each screen plot

(I used Imagio just for checking, but it redundant)

Comment: Try using the `agg` backend without interactive mode being on.

Comment: Ok after some investigation, I think the problems come from the looped line: fig.canvas.draw(). Unfourtantly, without it, I receive an error while trying to use .canvas.tostring_rgb(). Is any other way to turn a plot to a nparray? Should I use something like FuncAnimate or pyqtgraph?

Comment: No you should use the agg backend and turn interactive mode off.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but still no improvement. I attached above my full code. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `plt.ioff()` to turn off interactive mode. This should prevent your figures from being drawn unless you explicitly call `draw()` or some other function.

SO Post on the semantics of ioff(): [Exact semantics of Matplotlib's "interactive mode" (ion(), ioff())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130341/exact-semantics-of-matplotlibs-interactive-mode-ion-ioff)

As well as a link to the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ioff.html