# Showing the plot window more than once

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
import pylab
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
plotting=pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show(plotting)
```

The code above (specifically the last line) would pop up the graph below:

[image: The result when the code is run]

If I close the graph window, and run the last line (`>>>pylab.show(plotting)`) again, the graph would not pop up again. Why is that so?
The code above was run in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Did you close the first window?

Comment: @Ignato: Yes, I close the first window after it pops up and that I try to show it again using the show() function but it does not work.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2399978/723891) "With Matplotlib prior to version 1.0.1, show() should only be called once per program..." but "with Matplotlib version 1.0.1+, show() can be called multiple times" is not true, I have 1.1.1 and still can't call it twice.

Comment: @Igonato I think it means 'won't blow up if called more than once'.  I think it used to include code that started the GUI main loop.  When you close the gui window, there are call backs that remove figure from the structure that `pyplot` uses to keep track of it's figures hence `show` will do nothing if it does not know about any figures to show.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you close the window python tears down and deletes the figure.  Calling `show` again does nothing because there is no figure to show.

Passing an arguement to `show` like you do here does nothing ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show)).  The only argument that `show` takes is a key-word argument of `block`.