# How to get pyplot to put multiple lines in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to replace `plt.hold()` which accumulates lines in a figure.

Research: Several posted suggestions to this issue say to use multiple
`plt.plot(x,y)` commands followed by `plt.show()`. On my system (Python 3.6) that
prints only the content of the last `plt.plot()` call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
a = np.sin(t)
b = np.cos(t)

plt.plot(t, a, 'b') 
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of blue sine wave]

Adding another plt.plot() call clears the first line

```
plt.plot(t, a, 'b') 
plt.plot(t, b, 'g')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of a green cosine wave]

A method that works is to put them all in one plt.plot() call.

```
plt.plot(t, a, 'r--', t, b, 'b') 
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of 2 sine/cosine waves]

But I have five lines with labels to plot so this would be a long, hard-to-read
argument list.

How can I define each of the lines individually for one figure?

Comment: Running your code I get lines plotted on the same plot (which is what I would expect). Can you provide some more details about your setup?

Comment: Same as above. matplotlib 2.2.3

Comment: `matplotlib` accumulates the graphs drawn by multiple calls to `plt.plot()` by default. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805456/1102056

Comment: my matplotlib version is 2.1.2

Comment: There are numerous examples showing that it works so there must be something wrong with my installation.

Comment: `plt.show()` was designed with the expectation that it be called [only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724812/190597). So normally you would just call all the `plt.plot` commands first, then `plt.show()` at the end. If you want to make an animation, [use `matplotlib.animation`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html). Then you could allow the user to pause the animation on click events, [for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16733373/190597).

Comment: It's not necessarily the installation. It might be the way you execute this code. If it is in a script which you call via python, you will sure get 2 lines as expected in any matplotlib version. But if you run this differently, something might prevent that from happening.

Comment: `plt.hold()` will toggle the hold state, which make the latter plotting clear the `Axes`.  The default setting will not. You should check previous code for this state change. Or just do `plt.hold(True)`  to reset it.

Comment: I was troubleshooting a script that seemed to quit working when the hold calls were removed.  Today the simple plot example worked until the problem script ran; then the simple script would print only the last .plot line.

Comment: After I restarted the IDE and fixed a problem in the main script (passing a string used as a value on the Y axis) everything worked as expected.  Seems like something was getting screwed up in the environment.

Comment: My script creates plots for each of 50 tests of 20 units.  During development it had both `plt.savefig()` and `plt.show()` calls.  When the script is run in File Explorer, the `show` call displays each figure and doesn't proceed until you close it.  So how should I reset the `plt.plot()` queue (?) so it creates the files without using show?

Comment: Found the answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106288/matplotlib-pyplot-will-not-forget-previous-plots-how-can-i-flush-refresh/17107568). Use `plt.gcf().clear()` instead of `plt.show()`