# matplotlib show figure again

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure()

ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)

figure.show()  # figure is shown in GUI

# How can I view the figure again after I closed the GUI window?

figure.show()  # Exception in Tkinter callback... TclError: this isn't a Tk application
figure.show()  # nothing happened
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I get the previous plot back if I have called figure.show()?
2. Is there a more convenient alternative to `figure.add_suplot(111)` if I have multiple figures and thus `from pylab import *; plot(..); show()` seems not a solution I'm looking for.

And what I eagerly want is

```
showfunc(stuff) # or
stuff.showfunc()
```

where `stuff` is an object containing all the plots arranged in one picture, and `showfunc` is STATELESS(I mean, each time I call it, I behaves as if it's first time called). Is this possible when working with `matplotlib`?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here. Which previous plot are you referring to?

Comment: @ebarr I mean, how can I view the figure again after I closed the GUI window? Create a `figure` and `plot` again? I assume there should be a better way of doing this.

Comment: So `show` should only be run once in a script, as it starts the Tk mainloop running. The docs say "New in version v1.0.0: show now starts the GUI mainloop only if it isn’t already running. Therefore, multiple calls to show are now allowed.". Could you add a bit more information about what you need this functionality for? Are you building a GUI, or do you just want to look at plots one after another?

Comment: what version of `matplotlib` are you using?

Comment: @ebarr Look at plots one after another.

Comment: @behzad.nouri version 1.2.1

Comment: @ebarr What I really want is to trigger `show` in a STATELESS way. Is there an alternative `show` function or method, `showfunc(figure)` or  `figure.showfunc()` can be do the displaying task without change the `figure` object or any global variables?

Comment: There are some good answers to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397791/how-can-i-show-figures-separately-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a satisfactory answer, so I handle this problem by writing a custom `Figure` class extending `matplotlib.figure.Figure` and providing a new `show()` method, which create a `gtk.Window` object each time called.

```
import gtk
import sys
import os
import threading

from matplotlib.figure import Figure as MPLFigure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg as NaviToolbar


class ThreadFigure(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, figure, count):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.figure =   figure
        self.count  =   count
    def run(self):
        window  =   gtk.Window()
        # window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

        window.set_default_size(640, 480)
        window.set_icon_from_file(...)  # provide an icon if you care about the looks

        window.set_title('MPL Figure #{}'.format(self.count))
        window.set_wmclass('MPL Figure', 'MPL Figure')

        vbox    =   gtk.VBox()
        window.add(vbox)

        canvas  =   FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        vbox.pack_start(canvas)

        toolbar =   NaviToolbar(canvas, window)
        vbox.pack_start(toolbar, expand = False, fill = False)

        window.show_all()
        # gtk.main() ... should not be called, otherwise BLOCKING


class Figure(MPLFigure):
    display_count = 0
    def show(self):
        Figure.display_count += 1 
        thrfig = ThreadFigure(self, Figure.display_count)
        thrfig.start()
```

Make this file as start file of `IPython`. And

```
figure = Figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(211)
... (same story as using standard `matplotlib.pyplot` )
figure.show()

# window closed accidentally or intentionally...

figure.show()
# as if `.show()` is never called
```

Works! I never touched GUI programming, and don't know if this would have any side-effect. Comment freely if you think something should be done that way.

Comment: This must be one of the most useful matplotlib workarounds I have ever encountered. Well done for this solution. Getting out of the arcane Tcl/Tk windowing system and into Gtk is indeed a liberation and solves many of the other associated matplotlib misbehaviours with threading, etc.