# Sypder: How to make pandas.plot(subplots =True) show again, after closing plot window?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, spyder

I have created subplots on entire pandas dataframe `df` using following

```
plots = df.plot(subplot=True, layout=(2,3))
```

After this I do get the plot in separate window in Spyder.
However,if I close this window and want to display plots again, I am not able to do it. `plots.show()` does not work since `plots` is created as numpy array. I looked into two other similar posts, but can't figure it out.
1. [Matplotlib: how to show plot again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404365/matplotlib-how-to-show-plot-again)
2. [matplotlib show figure again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729206/matplotlib-show-figure-again)

Comment: I think you can set the preference in Tools-->Preferences-->IPython console-->Graphics tab but I think you would need to re-start Spyder for the changes to take place

Comment: @Nev1111 : Since it involves restarting, I will have to try it later and let you know if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate figure and axes object and pass the axes to `pandas.plot`. This allows you to keep the figure open without blocking your code. I like this because I can update the figure and use `fig.canvas.draw` followed by `fig.show` to show updates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({x: range(5) for x in 'abcdef'})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, subplots=True, layout=(2,3))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Then if you close the figure window you can bring it back with another call to `fig.show`. You can also modify an individual subplot like I mentioned earlier.

```
plots[0,0].axhline(3)
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems independent of the use of `plt.subplots`. So if you think `fig.show()` is a solution here, `plots[0,0].figure.show()` would as well.