# Creating and referencing separate matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What's the best practice to create multiple separate plots using matplotlib, so they can be called later or output into a pdf report? I'm a bit unclear as to how to do this in a way that retains each plot in memory (like we could with dataframes) for later reference.

Suppose we have this code:

```
%pylab inline
x1 = np.random.randn(50)*100
y1 = np.random.randn(50)*100
x2 = np.random.randn(50)*100
y2 = np.random.randn(50)*100
```

and the intent is to create 2 separate plots of (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and 'save' them in some way to be referenced later. the intent is to be able to output these into a PDF (perhaps via reportlab). the relationship between "figures", "subplots" and "axes" is confusing to me and not sure what is optimal for this purpose. i started with an approach like:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'r', alpha = 0.3)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'k', alpha = 0.7)
plt.show()
```

which does technically work, but i'm not sure how i can refer to these later. also, i am using a small example here for illustration, but in practice i may have many more of these.

Comment: Not exactly on spot, but almost a duplicate. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot). You likely want to `pyplot`. But you can still use `pylab`, and call plt.figure(N) subsequently, to select again your `N`-th figure and plot on that.

Comment: thanks, i actually am using pylot in my import. i have to include the %pylab inline bit because otherwise, the pictures do not show up

Comment: Then use sth like `fig,ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot([1,2,3]), fig.show()`. You can plot on the axis `ax` in as many places as you need in your code, and only in the end call `fig.show()`. For many figures, you would have `fig1,ax1`, you get the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things might make more sense if you start to use the object-oriented interface to matplotlib. In that case, you could do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'r', alpha = 0.3)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'k', alpha = 0.7)

plt.show()
```

In this way, its easy to see that `ax1` and `ax2` belong to the figure instance, `fig`. You can then later refer back to `ax1` and `ax2`, to plot more data on them, or adjust the axis limits, or add labels, etc., etc.

You can also add another figure, with its own set of subplots:

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(211)
```

and then you can save the given figures at any point, and know that you are always referring to the correct figure:

```
fig.savefig('figure1.png')
fig2.savefig('figure2.png')
```

Comment: i am a little confused as to the purpose of the final line: plt.show() in your example? the 2 subplots are shown whether or not i include that line

Comment: Ah yes, because you have the `%pylab inline` line there, the `plt.show` line is not needed. If you were working in a non-interactive environment, that would be required to display the plots

Answer (score 4):

With the implicit style that the question uses (where the figure object is *not* saved in a variable, and where plotting commands apply to the current figure), you can easily make a previous figure the current figure:

```
plt.figure(1)
```

will thus reactivate figure 1. `plt.savefig()` can then be used, additional plots can be made in it, etc.

Furthermore, you can also give a name to your figure when you create it, and then refer to it:

```
plt.figure("growth", figsize=…)
…
plt.figure("counts", figsize=…)
…
plt.figure("growth")  # This figure becomes the active one again
```

(the figure reference parameter is called `num`, but it doesn't have to be a number and [can be a string](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html), which makes for a clearer code).