# Matplotlib `figure.show()` does not show anything on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm using the latest matplotlib, version 2.0.0, installed via pip on Mac OSX Sierra. The problem is that the following example does not work as expected as no figure is shown. Note that I'm calling `show()` on the `figure1` object because I want to show only `figure1`. If I use `plt.show()` it works but it shows both `figure1` and `figure2` which I don't want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure1 = plt.figure()

# I need figure2 for something else but I don't want to show it.
figure2 = plt.figure()

figure1.show()

# The following would work, but I want to show
# only figure1 and not also figure2.
# plt.show()
```

Comment: maybe this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397791/how-can-i-show-figures-separately-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`figure.show()` makes sense in interactive mode, not for permanently showing a figure. So you need to use `plt.show()`. In order not to show the second figure, you may close it beforehands,

```
plt.close(figure2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I still need `figure2` for something else. Is there a way I can show only `figure1` without losing `figure2`. I mean I need `figure2` because say I want to save it to disk without showing it, can I still use it if I close it?

Comment: Uhm... are you sure about this? It seems like I'm still able to save it, even after calling `plt.close('all')`

Comment: You're right, even better. So just close the figure you don't want to show, and that's it.