# show graphs separately - troubles understand how to solve it

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to plot two graphs separately, but i couldn't. 
For this problem i have two lists, which are like:

```
year=[1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959]

pop=[2.53, 2.57, 2.62, 2.67, 2.71, 2.76, 2.81, 2.86, 2.92, 2.97]
```

Then i made a code which is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a line plot: year on the x-axis, pop on the y-axis
a=plt.plot(year,pop)

# Make a scatter plot: year on the x-axis, pop on the y-axis
b=plt.scatter(year,pop)

#show them
plt.show()
```

Of course i know that this plot both in same graph, i read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397791/how-can-i-show-figures-separately-in-matplotlib) but i couldn't fix my code. 
I am just a beginner so i came here for some help. Would you help me?

**EDIT**

I do not know really how to implement what is in the other answer, because i've never used plt.figure yet..
I think something like `add_subplot` should be used but don't know how.

Comment: What changes did you tried after reading that post you mention? Do add them to your question so we can help better. Also, take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge) ;)

Comment: @GrayCygnus i will do it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959]
pop = [2.53, 2.57, 2.62, 2.67, 2.71, 2.76, 2.81, 2.86, 2.92, 2.97]

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(year, pop)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(year, pop)
plt.show()
```

Adapted from: https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: ooohhhh it works. I will read that link to understand pyplot. Thank you a lot.