# Create multiple figures in pyplot, but only show one

Tags: matplotlib

I have a script that produces a number of different figures and saves the handles to a dictionary. Usually I want to plot all of them but sometimes I am working on a single one, and just want to plot that one.

My understanding is that `plt.show()` will show all the plots. It seems logical that if I allocate the figures handles (i.e. do `fig1 = plt.figure()`) and then use `fig1.show()` that should only show the figure associated with that handle.

Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y1 = np.random.rand(100)
y2 = np.random.rand(100)

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y1, 'o')

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y2, 'o')

fig1.show()
```

This seems to work but the figure immediately disappears after it is created. My understanding is that `fig1.show()` needs to be in a loop, since the class `Figure.show()` method does not invoke a while loop like `plt.show()` does.

I realise this is similar to the following question:
[How can I show figures separately in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397791/7530580) but the accepted answer doesn't seem to address the original problem (as is pointed out in the comments).

Is placing `fig1.show()` in a while loop the correct way? If so, how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a statement that waits for user input, then the figure will show, and close after you press a key:

```
fig1.show() 
raw_input()
```

Comment: So simple, yet does the trick perfectly! I was under the impression that the `show()` only appears momentarily before disappearing. I guess it displays the figure until the entire script is processed. Makes sense.

For Python 3 users, `raw_input()` was replaced with `input()`

Answer (score 2):

You might close all other figures except the one you want to show. Then calling `plt.show()` will only show the one figure that hasn't been closed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y1 = np.random.rand(100)
y2 = np.random.rand(100)

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y1, 'o')

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y2, 'o')

def figshow(figure):
    for i in plt.get_fignums():
        if figure != plt.figure(i):
            plt.close(plt.figure(i))
    plt.show()

figshow(fig2)
```

Comment: That works but I get bombarded with warning messages (`can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed`). 

I like your function though. Can be edited to allow for a list of figures, which is much faster than writing them all out.

Comment: The warnings could come from running this in interactive mode perhaps? Would `plt.ioff()` get rid of them?

Comment: No, `plt.ioff()` doesnt seem to change the warnings. Here is the full message. I get one of these for every closed plot:
    'can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed
        while executing
    "event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
        (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
        invoked from within
    "ttk::ThemeChanged"'

Comment: There seems to be a more severe problem with the tk backend involved. I tried with `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")` and it works fine.

Comment: Note that this should be fixed by https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12707 now. The bugfix may make it into the 3.0.2 release of matplotlib which is to appear pretty soon.